# How to calculate number of rows in a 1-to-many relationship in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I'm trying to do what I thought was a relatively simple calculation between 2 tables I have in the new PowerPivot add-on for Excel 2010.

My 2 tables loaded at setup as follows:

Table 1:
FooID, BarID, Name

Table 2:
BarID, Date

There is a 1 to many relationship between Table 1 and 2.

I want to add a calculated column to Table 1 that just does a sum of all the rows in Table 2.

I've tried this with no luck. The calculation results in null in every column. Excel isn't reporting an error, so it's not that the calculation is invalid, it's just doing somethign I"m not understanding.

```
=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table2), Filter(Table2, Table2[BARID] = Table1[BARID]))
```

I also tried something simpler that I thought would also work:

```
=COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE(Table2))
```

However that also results in null.

I have made sure that table 1 and table 2 have a relationship on BARID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

=COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE(Table2)) is the correct formula if there is an existing relationship.

Might it be that there simply are no matching keys?
You can try that by using your first formula and matching an explicit value eg.:

=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table2), Filter(Table2, Table2[BARID] = "SomeBARIDFromTable2"))

The above formula works on tables regardless of wheter a relationship is defined. 
HTH,
Hrvoje